# How can I manage a database server with Terraform

Tags: mysql, database, terraform

I'm just learning terraform and I had a question about the accepted way of handling a database server.

Let's say you have 1 database server. A change to it in terraform requires that server to be destroyed and recreated.

How would one handle transferring data from the previous database server to the new one with terraform?

Thank you!

Comment: What kind of changes are you making that forces the database to be destroyed and recreated?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I'm more interested in what the accepted way to handle such a case is. Unless the accepted way is to manually do a SQL Dump and then SQL Import. But I figured there was a "Terraform"/Automation way to do things. Such a case might be changing server models that doesn't support a rolling upgrade(such as OVH)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Managing state is hard.

In my experience the best thing is to offload that state where possible to managed services such as Amazon's RDS. RDS then allows for you to in place modify most things you would do in typical usage patterns (increase the size of the instance, move to a HA pair, upgrade the engine version) with little to no downtime depending on the action being performed.

If you have to manage state on instances/VMs you will want to handle these very differently to your stateless, more ephemeral instances where these can be easily thrown away regularly and replaced with another instance assuming you have some automation/a service that allows you to maintain uptime goals such as using blue/green deployment patterns or rolling deployments.

With state you will need to safely manage the actual stateful part which is normally some form of disk that is hopefully network attached in some way and can be re-attached to a different instance.

A very basic example might be something like the following:

```
resource "aws_volume_attachment" "database_volume" {
  device_name = "/dev/sdh"
  volume_id   = "${aws_ebs_volume.database.id}"
  instance_id = "${aws_instance.database.id}"
}

resource "aws_instance" "database" {
  ami               = "ami-21f78e11"
  availability_zone = "us-west-2a"
  instance_type     = "t1.micro"

  tags {
    Name = "Database Server"
  }
}

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "database" {
  availability_zone = "us-west-2a"
  size              = 1

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy
  }
}
```

This will create an EC2 instance and a separate EBS volume that will be attached to the instance by Terraform. If the instance needs to be replaced by Terraform then Terraform will handle attaching the volume to the new instance when it comes up. You could also combine this with `create_before_destroy` on the instance resource to make Terraform replace the instance and re-attach the volume before destroying the old one.

If you don't have the ability to use network attached storage like with above then you are basically forced to have Terraform dump out the database and then re-import it on the new instance.

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful. I assume you’d adjust the data directory for MySQL onto the ebs volume?

Comment: Yep. Bear in mind that the above will probably tear the data out from the server so unless you've stopped activity to the database it's going to break things. Even then though I'd expect crash recovery to fix things when the new server starts but you may lose a small amount of data depending on your transaction model. Also the above is generally untested by me because, as said, I find it much easier to offload state to a separate service and manage it differently to my stateless instances.